# signal vs thread

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I am looking some info about reentrancy, then I encountered about signal and thread. What is the difference between the two?

Please advice.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing apples and oranges.   [Signal Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_programming) is event driven programming and can be used to influence threads. However the signal programming paradigm can be used in a single threaded application.

Comment: @sasayins: this is the book to start with, of you are thinking of *nix.

Answer (score 4):

To understand signals it is best to start by thinking about a single threaded program.  This program is doing whatever it does with its one thread and then a signal is delivered to it.  If the program has registered a signal handler (a function to call) for that signal then the normal execution of that program will be put on hold for a little bit while the signal handler function is called (very much like an hardware interrupt interrupts the operating system to run interrupt service routines) and run the function that the program has registered to handle that signal.  So with the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h> // for alarm

volatile int x = 0;

void foo(int sig_num) {
   x = sig_num;
}

int main(void) {
   unsigned long long count = 0;
   signal(SIGALRM, foo);
   alarm(1);  // This is a posix function and may not be in all hosted
              // C implementations.
              // SIGALRM will be sent to this process in 1 second.
   while (!x) {
        printf("not x\n");
        count++;
   }
   printf("x is %i and count = %llu\n", x, count);
}
```

The program will loop until someone sends it a signal (how this happens may differ by platform).  If the signal `SIGALARM` is sent then `foo` will set `x` and the loop will exit.  Exactly where in the loop foo is called is not clear.  It could happen just between the print and incrementing the count, just after the while conditional is tested, during the print, ... lots of places, really.  This is why signals may pose a concurrency or reentrantcy problem -- they can change things without the other code knowing that it happened.

The reason that `x` was declared as volatile was that without that many compilers might think "hey, no one in main changes x and main doesn't call any other functions, so x never changes" and optimize out the loop test.  Specifying `volatile` tells the C compiler that this variable can be changed by unseen forces (such as signal handlers, other threads, or sometimes even hardware in the case of memory mapped device control registers).

It was pretty easy to make sure that `x` was looked out for properly between both the signal handler and the main execution code because `x` is just an integer (load and store for it were probably single instructions assembly each), it was only altered by the one *thing* (the signal handler, rather than the main code) in this case, and it was only used as a simple boolean value.  If `x` were some other type, such as a string, then since signals can interrupt you at any time, the signal handler may overwrite part of the string while the main code was in the middle of reading the string.  This could have results as bad as someone freezing time while you were in the middle of brushing your teeth, replacing your toothbrush with a cobra, and then unfreezing time.

A little bit more on signals -- they are part of the C language, but most of their use is not really covered by C.  Many of the Linux, Unix, and POSIX functions that have to do with signals are not part of the C language, but it is difficult to come up with reasonable (and small) examples of signal use that doesn't rely on something not in the C standard, which is why I used the `alarm` function.  The `raise` function, which is part of C, can be used to send a signal to yourself, but it is more difficult to make examples for.

As scary as signals may seem now, most systems have more functions that make them much more easy to use.

## threads, finally

Threads execute concurrently, while signals interrupt.  While there are some threading libraries that actually implement threading in such a way that this is not really the case, it is best to think of threads this way.  Since computer programs are actually very limited in their ability to see what is going on threads can get in each others' way just like  signal handlers can get in the way of the main execution code (probably more often than signal handlers, though).

Imagine that you are about to brush your teeth again, but this time you are def and blind.  Now your roommate, who is also def and blind, comes in to fix the sink with some silicone sealer.  Just as you reach for the toothpaste he lays down the tube of silicone right on top of the tube of toothpaste and you grab the tube of silicone instead of the toothpaste.  Remember, since you are both blind and def (and somehow not bumping into each other) you both assume that no one else is using the sink, so you never realize that you have just put the silicone on your toothbrush, and your roommate doesn't realize that he is trying to fill the cracks between the tile and the back of the sink with toothpaste.

Luckily there are ways that threads can communicate to each other that something is currently in use so other threads should stay away (like locking the door while you brush your teeth).